# The range of graphic-card resolutions just shrank? How do video, graphic card, and monitor work to render final resolution?

Tags: display, video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

Yesterday when I connected my Dell Inspiron 1525 to my LCD TV Dynex DX-32L150A11 (native resolution 1366x768) by VGA, going to "Display Settings" in Windows Vista allowed me a wide range to adjust the 2nd monitor's resolution from 800x600 up to more than 1920x1080.

Nothing has changed but now the highest resolution I can select for the 2nd monitor (extended to the left) is only 1360x768. What's going on?

Is there anyway I can get the exact 1366x768?

If I play a 1080p (1920x1080) video with VLC-player and display it on the 2nd monitor, what is the resolution exported to the 2nd monitor before it gets scaled to fit the 2nd monitor's native resolution (1366x768)? Is it 1920x1080 (of the video) or 1360x768 (of the graphic card)?

How do the video file, graphic card, and the 2nd monitor work together to produce the resolution of the final image? They're all different, 1920x1080, 1360x768, and 1366x768.

How does resolution scaling work, for example, to scale a 1280x720 image to fit a 1366x768 when the ratios 1366/1280 and 768/720 are not integers? And vice versa? We can't have something like 1.5 or 1.7 pixels.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is really confusing

Comment: your asking way too many questions in 1 question, and all the questions don't really connect to 1 central point to give you an answer. You're thoughts are scattered all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**“Nothing has changed but now the highest resolution I can select for the 2nd monitor (extended to the left) is only 1360x768. What's going on?”**

The cable you are using to connect the pc to the television might be bad. I experienced a similar issue connecting my computer to my television. When I tried using a different cable, I could output at the correct resolution.

**“What is the resolution exported to the 2nd monitor before it gets scaled to fit the 2nd monitor's native resolution (1366x768)?”**

The resolution that is output from your computer is whatever resolution your graphics card is set to for the TV. In your particular scenario it would be 1360x768.

**“How do the video file, graphic card, and the 2nd monitor work together to produce the resolution of the final image?”**

When you play a video on your computer, whatever program you use to play the video (in your case VLC) is responsible for scaling the video resolution to fit the size of the program window. For example, when you play a 1920x1080 resolution video, VLC shrinks the resolution that is displayed onscreen to the size of the VLC player.

When your computer outputs a different resolution than the native resolution of your TV, your TV is responsible for scaling it up or down to fit the TV screen.

**“How does resolution scaling work, for example, to scale a 1280x720 image to fit a 1366x768 when the ratios 1366/1280 and 768/720 are not integers?”**

When resolutions are scaled, they use the average color of surrounding pixels to calculate what color an actual screen pixel should show. For example, take a look at the diagram below demonstrating a 3:2 ratio scale.

[image: LCD Screen Pixel Scaling]